Undertow web server fails after restart with error "UT000196: Session with id xyz already exists"
I have a Java API server running on undertow with a React/TS front-end.
When the user is logged in, if I restart the web server, upon next incoming API request it fails when trying to get or create a http session with this error:
"UT000196: Session with id Bd7OOFzzr0HS6mRwGhaI0hifp7YbONJeU2PosKLd already exists"
This happens in io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager.createSession function. Any idea what causes this? I checked the code briefly on Github and looks like it is a normal hashmap with session identifiers, but I don't know why upon a restart, exact same session id is generated.
P.S: My deps:
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>



It's helpful if you tell which Undertow version you're using and also if you already tried latest. Because this looks very much like just a simple bug in some old Undertow version.
